# Eclipse Kepler Java show inherited Members (Ctrl+O twice) broken, perhaps due to updates?

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse is broken since this morning probably due to an automatic update (Java EE?).
Version is:

> Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Kepler Service
>   Release 1 Build id: 20130919-0819

Pressing Ctrl+O works, but pressing it again should show inherited members but it does not.
Here is what I have tried without success:

- cleaning the project
- close/open the project
- restarting eclipse with clean param

After additional research I found that this affects non-abstract classes that extend an abstract and generified class where the generic is found in an external dependency (jar). This fails:

```
public class MyProblematicClass extends MyAbstractClass<SomeProjectExternalClass> // fails
```

But this works:

```
   public class MyProblematicClass extends MyAbstractClass<SomeProjectInternalClass> // success
```

Could this be an Eclipse bug, any clues ?

Comment: Please Post the error that you are getting. Which Version of MyEclipse?

Comment: What is meant by "My Eclipse is broken" ?

Comment: @UmeshPatil This is a silent error it should show the inherited members but does nothing. I added the version...

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the preferences and bindings for the shortcut keys. 
Go to. Window->Preferences->General->Keys.. Type CTRL+O in the filter text box.

[image: Key Bindings for Eclipse]

If it still does not work try resetting the default options.

Further, I tried doing a CTRL+O twice on a package with an Abstract Class that extended no other class. It shows the outline as expected. Illustration below.

[image: Quick Outline for eclipse Kepler.]

Comment: I tried this without success, but you do deserve an upvote for the effort (may help others). In my case the abstract class is generified with a type declared in an external dependency (jar).